# Angular 6 ag-grid cell renderer click function

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

So I'm trying to setup ag-grid and I can't get one thing to work. I want to have a column that is actions. Then I want it to have a link or button that triggers a method in the component file.

For the column def I have the following. What am I doing wrong?

```
 {
    headerName: 'Actions',
    cellRenderer: params => {
      return `<a (click)="onEditClick("${params.data.hostname}")">Edit</a>`;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 21):

I use cellRenderFramework:

```
    {
    headerName: '', width: 30,
    cellRendererFramework: ActionCellRendererComponent,
    cellRendererParams: {
      icon: 'fa-download',
      action: this.downloadAttachmentAction
    }
  }
```

and than I have custom Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'cu-download-link-cell-renderer',
  template: `
  <div class="text-center">
    <i class="fa {{params.icon}}" (click)="onClick()" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>`
})
export class ActionCellRendererComponent {

    params;

    constructor() {
    }

    agInit(params): void {
        this.params = params;
        if (_.isNil(params.action)) {
            throw new Error('Missing action parameter for ActionCellRendererComponent');
       }
   }

   onClick(): void {
       this.params.action(this.params);
   }
}

export type CellAction = (params) => void;
```

Comment: Great Example! But this assumes my ColDef's are defined directly in my component. If I have abstracted out my ColDef's into a separate class, do you have a suggestion how I would reference the `action` function that might still live on the component?

Comment: @luker02 Did you find any solution for this without create a custom cellrender component?

Comment: @LucasSantos No, I did create a cellrenderer component. Then instead of directly calling my component function using the `action` param, I emitted events from the cellrenderer component and listened for them on my main component

Comment: hi @Peter1982, what is used of agInit() function?

Comment: @FaiZalDong components for AgGrid extends AgFrameworkComponent. Function agInit() is similar to ngOnInit().

Comment: what did you added `export type CellAction = (params) => void;` at the end? is that required?

Comment: This almost works, but unfortunately loses the component context when it calls back the function. Better to also pass the component context to the cell renderer.

Answer (score 8):

Use **cellRendererFramework** to add action Buttons.

**App.component.ts**

```js
columnDefs = [
  { headerName: 'First Name', field: 'firstName', sortable: true, filter: true },
  { headerName: 'Last Name', field: 'lastName', sortable: true, filter: true },
  { headerName: 'Email', field: 'email', sortable: true, filter: true },
  { headerName: 'User Name', field: 'userIdName', sortable: true, filter: true },
  { headerName: 'Role', field: 'role', sortable: true, filter: true },
  { headerName: 'Actions', field: 'action', cellRendererFramework: CellCustomComponent }];

rowData: any;

ngOnInit() {
  const empDatas = localStorage.getItem('user');
  const finalData = JSON.parse(this.empDatas);
  this.rowData = this.finalData;
}
```

In the above code, we can see **CellCustomComponent**. Create that component & add the buttons.

**cell-custom.component.html**

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-success" (click)="editRow()">Edit</button>
<button type="button" class="btn-success" (click)="viewRow()">View</button>
```

Now in the **cell-custom.component.ts** add the functions

**cell-custom.component.ts**

```js
export class CellCustomComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;
  params: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  agInit(params) {
    this.params = params;
    this.data = params.value;
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  editRow() {
    let rowData = this.params;
    let i = rowData.rowIndex;
    console.log(rowData);
  }

  viewRow() {
    let rowData = this.params;
    console.log(rowData);
  }
}
```

After this we need to add this component in **App.module.ts**

**app.Module.ts**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, CellCustomComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AgGridModule.withComponents([AppComponent])
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [CellCustomComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now we can trigger a method in the component file using Button.

[image: Ag-Grid Angular 7]

Comment: can you tell me sir how to open tooltip after hover any button of cell render?

Answer (score 1):

it has been perfect!
Thank you

prebilling-view.component.ts (cellRendererParams: { context: this })

```
 {
field: 'adjustmentUnit',
  tooltipField: 'adjustmentUnit',
  cellRendererParams: { context: this },
  cellRendererSelector: (params: any) => {
    const component = {
      component: 'textAreaVueRenderer',
      params: { values: true, textAlign: 'right', typeValue:false}
    }
    return component;
  },
  cellStyle: { textAlign: 'right' },
  headerClass: 'textRight',
},
```

function in prebilling-view.component.ts

```
onEditChange(val:string, index:any){
console.log("valor: "+ val)
console.log("index: "+ index)
```

}

input cellRenderSelector textAreaVueRender

```
  <input *ngIf="editEnabled"
            type="number"
            (input)="inputNegativeChangeHandler($event)"/>
```

function in cellRenderSelector textAreaVueRender component

```
 inputNegativeChangeHandler($event: any) {

this.params.context.onEditChange($event.target.value,this.params.rowIndex);
```

}

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30439986)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the **cellRendererFramework** to handle the rendering.

In your columnDefs:

```
this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'Header Name', field: 'field',
    cellRendererFramework: ColRenderer,
    cellRendererParams: { context: this },
    sortable: true, filter: true
  },
  ...
 ];
```

Then in your ColRenderer:

```
@Component({
  template: `<a (click)="clickHandler(rowData)">{{rowData.Member}}</a>`
})
export class ColRenderer implements ICellRenderer {
  public rowData: any;
  private params: any;

  public agInit(params: { data: any, context: any }) {
    this.rowData= params.data;
    this.params = params;
  };

  public clickHandler(data: any) {
    this.params.context.onEditClick(data);
  }
  ...
}
```

Change the names above obviously as needed. Just know the **context** is the key. You pass the context of your component to the renderer then use that context to call the function you want on click within your renderer.