# How to add Dropdown in Ag-Grid Angular?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid-community. I have tried cell render technique i.e [Angular 6 ag-grid cell renderer click function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990806/angular-6-ag-grid-cell-renderer-click-function) in which I add Dropdown . And Not worked

Answer (score 2):

Here Is Example Of DropDown...

```
 {
            headerName: 'Dropdown', field: 'dropdown',
            cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
            width: 140,          
            editable: true,

            cellEditorParams: (params) => {
            values: Get All Dropdown List
            },
            
            valueSetter: (params) => {
              if (params.newValue) {
               params.data.instrumentType = params.newValue;
                return true;
              }
              return false;
            }
 },
```